# HMAC SHA 384 on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, hmac

My code looks like this (using CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h):

```
- (NSString*) preperingCryptedData: (NSString*) data withKey: (NSString*) key {

    NSData* dataToHash = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSData* keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Utility: preperingCryptedData - Data to Crypt: %@ and key %@\n...\n...\n...\n",dataToHash,keyData);

    NSMutableData *dataHash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA384, keyData.bytes, keyData.length, dataToHash.bytes, dataToHash.length, dataHash.mutableBytes);

    NSString* readyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataToHash encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Utility: preperingCryptedData call, result :%@\n...\n...\n...\n",readyString);

    return readyString;
}
```

When I used code from: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444507/using-commoncrypto-commonhmac-to-encrypt-some-data-and-always-comes-back-null) I got my string decoded without the Key. What am I doing wrong? How it's possible to encode message without the key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problem with the code:

1) You are using `dataToHash` as the output instead of `dataHash`.

2) `dataHash` is not a UTF8 data representation so it can not be successfully converted into a `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the accepted answer. Provide working code.

```
 - (NSString *)sha384:(NSString*)data withKey:(NSString *)key {

    NSData* dataToHash = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData* keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    unsigned char digest[CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA384, keyData.bytes, keyData.length, dataToHash.bytes, dataToHash.length, digest);

    NSString *sha384Str;
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    sha384Str = output;
    return sha384Str;
}
```